# Is it possible for class activation maps where the predicted class has no activations?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, pytorch

I'm trying out grad CAM from the [captum library in pytorch](https://captum.ai/api/layer.html#gradcam) for a 3 class image classifier that uses transfer learning on resnet50. The model has good accuracy, but when I was looking at the generated gradCAM images, one of the images had the correct prediction but the gradCAM image had no activations for the predicted class. Instead it had activations for another class. Does this make sense or did I do something wrong in applying gradCAM? In other words, is it possible to have no activations for the predicted class?

Here is how I apply gradCAM

```
layer_gc = LayerGradCam(model, model.extractor.extractor[-2][-1].conv3)

# get for each class 
attr_1 = layer_gc.attribute(img, 0, relu_attributions=True)
attr_2 = layer_gc.attribute(img, 1, relu_attributions=True)
attr_3 = layer_gc.attribute(img, 2, relu_attributions=True)
pred = model(img)
```

To visualize the activation maps (original image is 224x224).

```
plt.imshow(original_img_pix)
plt.imshow(skimage.transform.resize(attr_1.detach().cpu().numpy()[0][0], (224,224)), alpha=0.5, cmap='jet')
plt.axis("off")
```

The resulting image for class 3, which is the predicted class, is only blue, with no red or yellow as expected like below.
[image: Cat class activation map with activations on the cat's face as red and yellow]

I also checked the output of the layer before softmax is applied, and it is `[-0.5133612, -0.5000069,  0.9999023]`, which suggests that it is very confident in it's prediction in the 3rd class, and it's correct, but the overlay of attr_3 which corresponds to that class is empty. Additionally, in other images this does not happen so I am quite confused.

P.S if it helps, here is the model architecture summary:

```
Net(
  n_classes=3, d_emb=256, normalize=True, scale=False, 
  (extractor): Extractor(
    (extractor): Sequential(
      (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
      (1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (4): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (5): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (3): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (6): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (3): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (4): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (5): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(1024, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (7): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(1024, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): BatchNorm2d(2048, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (8): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
    )
  )
  (embedding): Embedding(
    d_emb=256, normalize=True, 
    (fc): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=256, bias=True)
  )
  (classifier): Classifier(
    n_classes=3, d_emb=256, normalize=True, 
    (fc): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=3, bias=False)
  )
)
```